# Contact Form PHP Email Script

Tags: php, forms, email, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am having problem with the email script on my site.

I used this files

https://jonbake.com/blog/bootstrap-3-contact-form-with-captcha/

but I add some fields. It is sending to my email but I'm not receiving all the data inputted on the fields.

Here is my HTML Form

```
<form role="form" id="feedbackForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your name.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your name.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company_name" name="company_name" placeholder="Company">
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your name.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a message.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectbasic">How did you hear about us?</label>
                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>Search engine</option>
                    <option>Microsoft DPE</option>
                    <option>Microsoft event</option>
                    <option>Social media</option>
                    <option>Word of mouth</option>
                    <option>Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          <img id="captcha" src="library/vender/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
          <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'library/vender/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Show a Different Image</a><br/>
          <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha_code" id="captcha_code" placeholder="For security, please enter the code displayed in the box." />
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter the code displayed within the image.</span>
          </div>

          <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a the security code.</span>
          <button type="submit" id="feedbackSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">Send Feedback</button>
        </form>
```

This is my PHP Script

```
<?php
 //start a session -- needed for Securimage Captcha check
 session_start();

 //add you e-mail address here
 define("MY_EMAIL", "dummyemail@gmail.com");

/**
 * Sets error header and json error message response.
 *
 * @param  String $messsage error message of response
 * @return void
 */
function errorResponse ($messsage) {
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
die(json_encode(array('message' => $messsage)));
}

/**
 * Return a formatted message body of the form:
 * Name: <name of submitter>
 * Comment: <message/comment submitted by user>
 *
 * @param String $name     name of submitter
 * @param String $messsage message/comment submitted
 */
function setMessageBody ($first_name, $last_name, $email, $message, $selectbasic) {
  $message_body = "Name: " . $first_name. $last_name. "\n\n";
  $message_body = "Email: " . $email."\n\n";
  $message_body = "Company Name: " . $company_name."\n\n";
  $message_body .= "Message:\n" . nl2br($message);
  $message_body .= "How did you hear about us?:" . $selectbasic."\n\n";
  return $message_body;
}
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];  
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$company_name = $_POST['company_name']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];
$selectbasic = $_POST['selectbasic'];

header('Content-type: application/json');
//do some simple validation. this should have been validated on the client-side also
if (empty($email) || empty($message)) {
errorResponse('Email or message is empty.');
}

//do Captcha check, make sure the submitter is not a robot:)...
include_once './vender/securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();
if (!$securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code'])) {
  errorResponse('Invalid Security Code');
}

//try to send the message
if(mail(MY_EMAIL, "Feedback Form Results", setMessageBody($_POST["first_name"],         
$_POST["last_name"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["selectbasic"], $message), "From:    
 $first_name, $last_name")) {
echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Your message was successfully submitted.'));

  } else {
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Unexpected error while attempting to send e-   
 mail.'));
 }
 ?>
```

I don't know what's wrong but I need to capture all the data.

Thanks for your help.

This what I am getting after putting DOT before equal sign

[image]

New Code I'm using achieving the image above

```
<?php
 //start a session -- needed for Securimage Captcha check
 session_start();

 //add you e-mail address here
 define("MY_EMAIL", "aareyes00@ymail.com");

 /**
 * Sets error header and json error message response.
 *
 * @param  String $messsage error message of response
 * @return void
 */
 function errorResponse ($messsage) {
 header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
 die(json_encode(array('message' => $messsage)));
 }

/**
 * Return a formatted message body of the form:
 * Name: <name of submitter>
 * Comment: <message/comment submitted by user>
 *
 * @param String $name     name of submitter
 * @param String $messsage message/comment submitted
 */
 function setMessageBody ($first_name, $last_name, $email, $company_name, $message,    
 $selectbasic) {
 $message_body .= "First Name: " . $first_name."\n\n";
 $message_body .= "Last Name: " . $last_name."\n\n";
 $message_body .= "Email: " . $email."\n\n";
 $message_body .= "Company Name:" . $company_name."\n\n";
 $message_body .= "Message:" . $message. "\n\n";
 $message_body .= "How did you hear about us?" . $selectbasic."\n\n";
 return $message_body;
 }
 $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];  
 $email = $_POST['email']; 
 $company_name = $_POST['company_name']; 
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $selectbasic = $_POST['selectbasic'];

 header('Content-type: application/json');
 //do some simple validation. this should have been validated on the client-side also
 if (empty($email) || empty($message)) {
 errorResponse('Email or message is empty.');
 }
 //do Captcha check, make sure the submitter is not a robot:)...
 include_once './vender/securimage/securimage.php';
 $securimage = new Securimage();
 if (!$securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code'])) {
 errorResponse('Invalid Security Code');
 }

 //try to send the message
 if(mail(MY_EMAIL, "Feedback Form Results", setMessageBody($_POST["first_name"],      
 $_POST["last_name"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["message"], $_POST["selectbasic"]), "From:    
 $first_name, $last_name")) {
 echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Your message was successfully submitted.'));

 } else {
 header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
 echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Unexpected error while attempting to send e-   
 mail.'));
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could give you better solution if you can give me what data you receiving in email.
But as it seems, you just missed some dot (.) in function setMessageBody(...) on these line-

```
$message_body = "Email: " . $email."\n\n";
$message_body = "Company Name: " . $company_name."\n\n";
```

Add dot (.)-

```
$message_body .= "Email: " . $email."\n\n";
$message_body .= "Company Name: " . $company_name."\n\n";
```

Check your select option. Your line

```
<option>Select</option>
<option>Search engine</option>
<option>Microsoft DPE</option>
<option>Microsoft event</option>
<option>Social media</option>
<option>Word of mouth</option>
<option>Other</option>
```

Will be like-

```
<option>Select</option>
<option value="Search engine">Search engine</option>
<option value="Microsoft DPE">Microsoft DPE</option>
<option value="Microsoft event">Microsoft event</option>
<option value="Social media">Social media</option>
<option value="Word of mouth">Word of mouth</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
```

Comment: Hello! putting a DOT before the equal sign helps but I still have missing fields. I already edit my post. I attached there the email that is sending to me.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see any image! Can you upload the screenshot elsewhere & give me the image link?

Comment: Missing is the company name. I will edit my post and put the new php code that I am using

Comment: Hey thanks to your help. Adding that dot helps! I already got all the details :)

Comment: Also check the select option update. If you not do that as I stated you can't have what he selected.

Comment: Thanks! do you know how to add audio captcha here?

Comment: Select any audio captcha script by searching in Google & if you can't implement let me know!

Comment: but I already have a captcha image that I used from this link https://jonbake.com/blog/bootstrap-3-contact-form-with-captcha/ but I it doesn't provide the audio?

Comment: no, it isn't! You have to use another captcha module! May be ReCaptcha will be best suite for you.

Comment: can I have a link for that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok, just modify a little :

```
<form role="form" id="feedbackForm" method="post">
```

Add method attribute in your form tag, because in your code you didn't define any post method, and [default post method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) is `get`. So you have two option.

**One modify `<form id="feedbackForm" method="post">`**

OR

**Modify all `$_POST` to `$_GET`**

Answer (score -1):

Update your HTML form like this:

```
<form action="email.php" method="post" role="form" id="feedbackForm">
```

Try this `email.php` script:

```
<?php

//start a session -- needed for Securimage Captcha check
session_start();

//add you e-mail address here
define("MY_EMAIL", "dummyemail@gmail.com");

//error responder
function errorResponse($messsage)
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    die(json_encode(array(
        'message' => $messsage
    )));
}

//parse input
$first_name   = isset($_POST['first_name'] ? $_POST['first_name'] : '');
$last_name    = isset($_POST['last_name'] ? $_POST['last_name'] : '');
$email        = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$company_name = isset($_POST['company_name']) ? $_POST['company_name'] : '';
$message      = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';
$selectbasic  = isset($_POST['selectbasic']) ? $_POST['selectbasic'] : '';

//do some simple validation. this should have been validated on the client-side also
if (empty($email) || empty($message)) {
    errorResponse('Email or message is empty.');
}

//do Captcha check, make sure the submitter is not a robot:)...
include_once './vender/securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();
if (!$securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code'])) {
    errorResponse('Invalid Security Code');
}

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' . MY_EMAIL . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $first_name $last_name <$email>\r\n";

// Generate Message
$message_body = "Name: ". $first_name. $last_name. "<br>";
$message_body = "Email: ". $email ."<br>";
$message_body = "Company Name: ". $company_name ."<br>";
$message_body .= "Message:<br>". nl2br($message) ."<br>";
$message_body .= "How did you hear about us?: " . $selectbasic."\n\n";

//try to send the message
if (@mail(MY_EMAIL, "New message from $first_name $last_name", $message_body, $headers)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'message' => 'Your message was successfully submitted.'
    ));
} else {
    errorResponse('Unexpected error while attempting to send e-mail.');
}

?>
```